# Can I use google places API (auto-complete) and Mapkit together?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I want to allow the user to select a place (Google places auto complete API) and then show the place selected on map. 
Can I use google places API for iOS and apple map (Mapkit) for this purpose? Map and the selection feature will be on separate view controllers but according to https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete ,

> displaying Google Places on a non-Google map is against their terms of
>   service.

So if I use them together, Will my app wont be accepted while uploading or app store? Or what will happen?

Comment: I can't see Apple having any objections to this in app review, even though they would probably like you to just use MapKit, it wouldn't really be fair for them to penalise you for using a publicly available SDK. What Google may think is a different matter however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google Terms of Use:

> (d) No Use With Non-Google Maps. Customer will not use the Google Maps
>   Core Services in a Customer Application that contains a non-Google
>   map. For example, Customer will not (i) display Places listings on a
>   non-Google map, or (ii) display Street View imagery and non-Google
>   maps in the same Customer Application.

As for me it says that we can't show places list provided by Google Places API on non-Google map. But it says nothing about displaying place that was chosen from Google Places list.

More then that, I have app with exact functionality that you want and I didn't had any issues with App Store submission.